# Show that $(p^2+3)x^2+2pqx+q^2=0$ has no real roots no matter the value of $p$ and $q$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I sat for an exam today and came across this question.

> Show that $(p^2+3)x^2+2pqx+q^2=0$ has no real roots no matter the value of $p$ and $q$.

I tried using the $b^2-4ac$ but wasn't too sure if it was right to use this formulae. Anyone can help? Do ask if you have any questions. (I'm not really sure what to put as my tag so if this ends up somewhere it shouldn't be, I'm sorry)

Comment: Show that the discriminant is negative.

Comment: When you tried $b^2-4ac$ what did you get?

Comment: Plus, if you are going to spend time on this website, it would be beneficial to learn to type equations in MathJax. Here's a tutorial - https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The statement is trivially false, it has a root $x = 0$ when $q = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\Delta'=p^2q^2-(p^2+3)q^2=-3q^2\le0.$$

When $q=0$, there is the double root $x=0$.